# Is it possible to verify the color of an element using Detox?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, testing, automated-tests, detox

Let's say I found an element by id and want to check its color, how would one do it?
I tried:

```js
const attr = await element(by.id("the id")).getAttributes();
console.log(attr);
```

this prints out the height, width, etc. but not the color.